# Can a PHP define be used for a function with an argument

Tags: php, superglobals

I am writing a script that generates HTML based on what is currently in a database and I prefer to have the HTML be formatted, particularly with tabs to show nesting. I have a simple function to generate some number of tabs:

```
function addTab($inNum) {
    $out = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $inNum; $i++) $out .= "\t";
    return $out;
}
```

For convenience of reading the PHP, I made this:

```
$T = "addTab";
```

So that I could just use `$T(5)` to say concatenate 5 `\t` to the string HTML. Personally I find this kind of syntax of pointing to a function by string to be unintuitive and functions that use it require `global $T`.

Is it possible to use a `define()` so that something like `T(5)` could be used within function scope?

Comment: Can't you just use `addTab()` directly? I feel `$T()` is harder to read than an actual function name.

Comment: Why not just do `function T($n) { return addTab($n); }`? I wouldn't really recommend it, but it has the same drawbacks as the approach you outlined.

Comment: @AlexisKing, I think that is an improvement, thanks. Still curious about the `define()` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot "define a function" in the way you desire.

Why not use:

```
function T($inNum)
{
    return addTab($inNum);
}
```

Then you can just write `T(5)`, as you mentioned.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you determine that it cannot be done? If the pointing of `T` to `addFunction` was ignored, could `T` be made to be a `define()` that returns a variable number of `\t`s? **Edit**: I believe something like this can be done in C (a define that takes an argument), and was wondering if PHP can do the same

Comment: Runtime definitions in PHP are not preprocessor definitions as in C. Definitions in PHP are essentially just glorified constant globals that do not require a preceding `$` token, and can only be defined to constant values. Definitions in C are essentially just dumb copy-paste operations, where the preprocessor replaces the defined token name with its value. See the PHP documentation itself at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: If you want, you could write `define('T1', addTab(1))`, `define('T2', addTab(2))`, etc. but there is no advantage to doing this over hardcoding the tabs in your output. The entire purpose of having the function return a variable number of tabs, based on some input, is that you do not know the number of tabs until runtime.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be kind of silly, I think I'll just stick with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

When you use `define` you define a constant.
According to manual:

`The value of the constant; only scalar and null values are allowed. Scalar values are integer, float, string or boolean values. It is possible to define resource constants, however it is not recommended and may cause unpredictable behavior.`

So you can't define a constant with the value of a function.

But still function variables are working in php:

```
function addTab($inNum) {
    $out = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $inNum; $i++) $out .= "*";
    return $out;
}
$T = 'addTab';
$r = $T(5);
var_dump($r);    // string(5) "*****"
```

Comment: I had just written a comment to inspector-g's answer, does this also disallow a `define()` that takes an argument and returns a string (bypassing the function `addTab()`)? **Edit**: Bypassing was the wrong word, I mean has the same effect as `addTab()` but a `define()`

Comment: I think if such opportunity was available, it was definitely described in a manual (or in comments to `define` function).